# Is it possible in sqlalchemy to indicate a table to select from and not select any column from it?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy I would like to do something like:

```
q = session.query(a, b.id, func.count(a.id))
q = q.outerjoin(b, b.id == a.b_id)
q = q.group_by(b.id)
```

However in most of sql implementations it is impossible to select fields that are not in group by clause.

Can I order sqlalchemy to select from table a, but not select any field directly from a? In this case I would be able to just change join order but I've got some complex queries that aren't so easy to modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `FROM` clause explicitly with [`select_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from):

```
session.query(b.id, func.count(a.id)).select_from(a).outerjoin(b, ...)...
```